Luau Correction system not works
function ProjectileModuleScript.CreateNewProjectile(settings)
local self = {}

    local defaults = {
        Gravity = 9.8,
        Include = workspace.empty:GetDescendants(),
        Wind = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0),
        DespawnTime = 10,
        Visualize = false
    }
    
    -- Iterate through the defaults table and use the settings values where available
    for key, value in pairs(defaults) do
        self[key] = settings[key] ~= nil and settings[key] or value
    end
    
    return self

end

Key Fixes:
The merging loop is correct in terms of checking if the settings table contains a value for each key. If a key is found in settings, it uses that value; otherwise, it defaults to the value from defaults.
The return self at the end ensures that the self table is returned properly after merging.
Explanation:
settings[key] ~= nil checks if a value for key exists in settings and uses it if available.
If the value doesn't exist, it falls back to the value from the defaults table.
If I use this function and pass the following settings table:
local settings = { Gravity = 1,  Include = workspace.empty:GetDescendants(), Visualize = false }

The self table will be:
{     Gravity = 1,     Include = workspace.empty:GetDescendants(),     Wind = Vector3.new(0, 0, 0),     DespawnTime = 10,     Visualize = false }

